# Adding height:100%; to elements gives me a scrollbar

Tags: css

Here's my html as basic as possible:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">foo</div>
    <div class="middle">foo</div>
    <div class="right">foo</div>
</div>
```

And here comes my css:

```
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
html, body { height: 100%; }
.wrapper { min-height: 100%; }
/* left, middle and right have float:left and a width. Also min-height:100%; */
```

So, I've tried everything. Added min-heigth: 100% to all, taken it away and then put it back. Still a scrollbar appears.

Any ideas?

Martti Laine

Comment: What browser are you seeing this in? I don't get a scrollbar using Firefox.

Comment: Which browsers and DOCTYPEs have you tried this with?

Comment: You could also try.. margin-bottom:-1px on .wrapper.

Comment: This happens on at least Chrome and Opera. DOCTYPE is xhtml transitional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
overflow:hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
html, body, .wrapper { 
  overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

By the way `.wrapper` should be `#wrapper` because it is assumed to be only once on a page.